# Amazon instances health check fails often since started auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

A couple of month ago we started testing on staging environment the auto scaling ability of amazon.

Since than, we created new images and launch configuration threw code and update the auto scaling at least twice a day.

The auto scaling has the proper cool down times and ELB health check by our application server response.

Recently, some instances which are connected to the ELB of the auto scaling has failed status check and they are imminently terminated.
Usually it is a proper behaviour of auto scaling, but it happens a lot.

Can someone tell from his experience if it failed status checked are increased when create new images couple of time in a day for a long time?

Comment: The the filed status check actually cause the termination, or is your Auto Scaling group configured to use ELB health checks (which might mean that a failed ELB health check led to instance termination)? What is the explanation provided in the `Scaling History` tab within the Auto Scaling console?

Comment: Elb health check that tells auto scaling to terminate. But the question is if the status check failed is typical to instances created by auto scaling from new image each time.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of **Status Checks** that are performed on Amazon EC2 instances.

From [Status Checks for Your Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html):

> **System Status Checks**
>
> Monitor the AWS systems required to use your instance to ensure they are working properly. These checks detect problems with your instance that require AWS involvement to repair. When a system status check fails, you can choose to wait for AWS to fix the issue, or you can resolve it yourself (for example, by stopping and starting an instance, or by terminating and replacing an instance).
>
> The following are examples of problems that can cause system status checks to fail:
>
> - Loss of network connectivity
> - Loss of system power
> - Software issues on the physical host
> - Hardware issues on the physical host
>
> **Instance Status Checks**
>
> Monitor the software and network configuration of your individual instance. These checks detect problems that require your involvement to repair. When an instance status check fails, typically you will need to address the problem yourself (for example, by rebooting the instance or by making instance configuration changes).
>
> The following are examples of problems that can cause instance status checks to fail:
>
> - Failed system status checks
> - Incorrect networking or startup configuration
> - Exhausted memory
> - Corrupted file system
> - Incompatible kernel

**Status Checks & Auto Scaling**

There is no reason why Auto Scaling should cause an increase in Status Check failures. There might be an issue with the AMI being used (eg incompatible kernel), but running that AMI under Auto Scaling would be no different to running it outside of Auto Scaling. Try launching an Amazon EC2 instance using the AMI without Auto Scaling to see if it causes failures.

**Auto Scaling & ELB Health Checks**

Auto Scaling can also be configured to use ELB Health Checks. This is where Auto Scaling 'trusts' the ELB Health Check and terminates instances if ELB determines that an instance is unhealthy. The benefit of this type of health check is that ELB can check a specific URL or port, which is more accurate than merely using the above status checks.

A poorly-configured ELB health check can cause Auto Scaling the 'thrash' by killing instances and launching them again. Be sure to provide sufficient cool-down time to allow an instance to start before applying ELB health checks.